# Replacing いい in ～て(も)いい & ～ないで(も)いい

Tags: grammar

Besides わるい, can we flexibly change the adjective いい in grammatical structures such as てもいい?
Moreover, can we completely change the entire いいです into like a phrase?

For example:

> このものを使かないでも時間がたくさんかかるでしょうね。

Comment: Can you give us a few concrete examples?

Comment: I've provided an example.

Comment: このものを使かないでも doesn't refer to your question. Even I make it これを使わないでも stands 'without using this' , not related with bad or good.